# mapstruct only convert parent fields when source bean and target bean both inheit parent using lombok

Tags: inheritance, lombok, mapstruct

As bellow, I have OpenSecretEntity which extends BasicEntity and OpenSecretDto which extends BasicDto.

When i use OpenSecretStructMapper with @Mapper of mapstruct to convert OpenSecretEntity to OpenSecretDto , the implementation of mapstruct only covnert fields in BasicEntity.

How can i fix it? Thanks

BasicEntity:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class BasicEntity {

    private Long id;
    private Date createAt;
    private String createBy;
    private Date updateAt;
    private String updateBy;
}
```

SecretEntity:

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OpenSecretEntity extends BasicEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String secretId;
    private String secretKey;
    private String remark;
    private Boolean enabled;
    private Date effectStart;
    private Date effectEnd;
}
```

BasicDto:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class BasicDto {
    private Long id;
    private String createBy;
    private Date createAt;
    private String updateBy;
    private Date updateAt;
}
```

SecretDto:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class OpenSecretDto extends BasicDto {

    private String remark;
    private String secretId;
    private String secretKey;
    private Date effectStart;
    private Date effectEnd;

}
```

mapstruct

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface OpenSecretStructMapper {

    OpenSecretDto toDto(OpenSecretEntity entity);

}
```

The implementation of SecretStructMapper

```java
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-06-29T11:30:42+0800",
    comments = "version: 1.5.3.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.18 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class OpenSecretStructMapperImpl implements OpenSecretStructMapper {

    @Override
    public OpenSecretDto toDto(OpenSecretEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        if (entity instanceof OpenSecretEntity) {
            return openSecretEntityToOpenSecretDto( (OpenSecretEntity) entity );
        }
        else {
            OpenSecretDto openSecretDto = new OpenSecretDto();

            openSecretDto.setId( entity.getId() );
            openSecretDto.setCreateBy( entity.getCreateBy() );
            openSecretDto.setCreateAt( entity.getCreateAt() );
            openSecretDto.setUpdateBy( entity.getUpdateBy() );
            openSecretDto.setUpdateAt( entity.getUpdateAt() );

            return openSecretDto;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public OpenSecretEntity toEntity(OpenSecretDto openSecretDto) {
        if ( openSecretDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        OpenSecretEntity openSecretEntity = new OpenSecretEntity();

        openSecretEntity.setId( openSecretDto.getId() );
        openSecretEntity.setCreateAt( openSecretDto.getCreateAt() );
        openSecretEntity.setCreateBy( openSecretDto.getCreateBy() );
        openSecretEntity.setUpdateAt( openSecretDto.getUpdateAt() );
        openSecretEntity.setUpdateBy( openSecretDto.getUpdateBy() );

        return openSecretEntity;
    }

    protected OpenSecretDto openSecretEntityToOpenSecretDto(OpenSecretEntity openSecretEntity) {
        if ( openSecretEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        OpenSecretDto openSecretDto = new OpenSecretDto();

        openSecretDto.setId( openSecretEntity.getId() );
        openSecretDto.setCreateBy( openSecretEntity.getCreateBy() );
        openSecretDto.setCreateAt( openSecretEntity.getCreateAt() );
        openSecretDto.setUpdateBy( openSecretEntity.getUpdateBy() );
        openSecretDto.setUpdateAt( openSecretEntity.getUpdateAt() );

        return openSecretDto;
    }
}
```

I wish mapstruct can convert all the fields in OpenSecretEntity include fields in BasicEntity to OpenSecretDto.
But i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To include also fields from BasicEntity you need to configure the mapper:

MapStruct documentation: [shared-configurations](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#shared-configurations)

Essentially you need to create a BaseMapperConfig where you map BaseEntity to BaseDto and then configure OpenSecretStructMapper to use BaseMapperConfig.

Instead, if you have problem using lombok along with mapstruct, you can check:

Mapstruct documentation: [lombok](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#lombok)